# Как вывести данные (String) в TextView (Вторая активити) из EditText (Первая активити)

Tags: java, android

В приложении две активити - первая содержит несколько EditText и Button (вызов 2й активити) ,
вторая - TextView. Как сделать, что бы введенные данные из EditText отобразились в TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добиться этого можно используя метод `putExtra`  .

Это добавит в интент данные из editText

```
 intent.putExtra("key", MyEditText.getText().toString());
```

на другой активити получаем интент, который ее вызвал :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

И вытягиваем из неё текст по ключу:

```
String str = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

ну и добавляем в TextView

Вот советую прочитать урок как раз по этой 
[теме](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html)

И вообще если занимаетесь изучением андроид, стоит пройти уроки с этого сайта, там получите ответы на многие подобные базовые вопросы

Comment: спасибо! Статья будет полезной!